# what is the negation of $\exists^{=1}x\phi(x)$?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I need to understand the negation of counting quantifiers, so in my understanding negation of $\exists^{=n}x \phi(x)$ should be $\exists^{<n}x \neg \phi(x) \lor \exists^{>n}x \neg \phi(x) $. Hence, the negation for $\exists^{=1}x\phi(x)$ is given as follows ?
$$\exists^{<1}x \neg \phi(x) \lor \exists^{>1}x \neg \phi(x)$$
Which can be written as follows ?
$$\phi(x) \lor \exists^{>1} x  \neg \phi(x)$$
Am I doing it right ?

Comment: We used to write $\exists!$ when there exists a unique...

Comment: not sure how do you get $\exists^{<1}x \neg \phi(x)\equiv\phi(x)$, it should be
$\exists^{<1}x \neg \phi(x)
\equiv\exists^{=0}x \neg \phi(x)
\equiv\forall x~ \phi(x)$

Comment: "not exists exactly one" is "Either 0 or more than one"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a good idea to say it out loud:

$\exists ^{=1} x\phi(x)$ means "there is exactly one $x$ such that $\phi(x)$". So the negation is that "there is not exactly one $x$ such that $\phi(x)$". In other words, either there are less than one $x$ such that $\phi(x)$ or there are more than one $x$ such that $\phi(x)$. So your answer (the first formulation) is nearly right, except that you have incorrectly negated $\phi(x)$.

The same ideas apply to any $n$.

As for the second formulation, $\exists^{<1}x \phi(x)$ is the same as $\neg \exists x \phi(x)$, which is the same as $\forall x \neg\phi(x)$. Sometimes people write $P(x)$ to mean the same as $\forall x P(x)$, but I think it would be confusing in this context.

Comment: Should we write $\forall x \lnot\phi(x) \lor...$?

Comment: I am sorry but less than one x such that $\phi(x)$ means  $\neg \phi(x)$, hence we have $\neg \phi(x) \lor \exists^{>1}x \phi(x)$

Comment: I added some comments about that. Let me know if there is more to clarify.

Comment: "So your answer is nearly right, except that you have incorrectly negated ()." I suppose you are referring to the $\phi(x)$ in the $\exists^{>n}$ part, where it should indeed occur unnegated. But this is not the only mistake: the $\phi(x)$ in the first disjunct should be negated.

Comment: @lemontree The negation of $\exists^{=1} x \phi(x)$ is $\exists^{<1} x \phi(x) \vee \exists^{>1} x \phi(x)$. Neither $\phi(x)$ should be negated. My addition comments make it clear that in the final formulation (with the implicit $\forall$), the $\phi(x)$ should be negated. (That latter formulation was added while I was writing out my answer, which is why the comments come at the end.)

Comment: Okay, your most recent edit makes that clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Not quite: The negation of the existence of exactly $n$ objects having the property $\phi$ is that either less than $n$ or more than $n$ objects *do* have the property $\phi$: There is no negation. Consider the statement "There is exactly one even prime number": This will be false either if there exist no even prime numbers at all, or if there exists more than one number which is even and prime; "even and prime" will be unnegated in both of those disjuncts.

So in general,

$$\neg \exists^{=n} x \phi(x)\\
= \exists^{<n} x \phi(x) \lor \exists^{>n} x \phi(x)$$

(For an derivation of how this equality comes about, see the last paragraph.)

---

Now for the meaning of $\exists^{<n} x \phi(x)$: This means that there do not exist $n$ objects which are mutually distinct and all have the property $x$, that is,

$$\exists^{<n} x \phi(x)\\
= \neg \exists x_1 \ldots \exists x_n (x_1 \neq x_2 \land \ldots \land x_1 \neq x_n \land \ldots \land x_{n-1} \neq x_n \land \phi(x_1) \land \ldots \phi(x_n)) $$

And $\exists^{>n}$ just means that there exist at least $n+1$ distinct objects with the property $\phi$, i.e.,

$$\exists^{>n} x \phi(x)\\
= \exists x_1 \ldots \exists x_n \exists x_{n+1} (x_1 \neq x_2 \land \ldots \land x_1 \neq x_{n+1} \land \ldots x_n \neq x_{n+1} \land \phi(x_1) \land \ldots \land \phi(x_{n+1})) $$

---

Thus, we have

$$\neg \exists^{=1}x \phi(x)\\
= \exists^{<1} x \phi(x) \lor \exists^{>1} x \phi(x)\\
= \neg \exists x_1 \phi(x_1) \lor \exists x_1 \exists x_2 (x_1 \neq x_2 \land \phi(x_1) \land \phi(x_2))\\
= \text{"There is no object of which $\phi$ holds, or there are at least two distinct objects of which $\phi$ holds"}
$$

If you want, you can rewrite $\neg \exists x \phi(x)$ as $\forall x \neg \phi(x)$, and, if your textbook permits for the convention of dropping universal quantifiers, rewrite $\forall x \neg \phi(x)$ as $\neg \phi(x)$, thereby obtaining

$$\neg \phi(x) \lor \exists x_1 \exists x_2 (x_1 \neq x_2 \land \phi(x_1) \land \phi(x_2))$$

Note that the negation of $\phi$ in the first disjuncts comes from $\neg \exists$ which is the translation of $\exists^{<1}x \phi(x)$, while $\phi$ in the second disjunct remains unnegated.

---

As suggested by Bram28 in the comments, this can be systematically derived from the positive =n quantifier. "Exactly $n$" means "at least $n$ and not more than $n$", that is,

$$\exists^{=n} x \phi(x)\\
= \exists^{\geq n} x \phi(x) \land \neg \exists^{\geq n+1} x \phi(x)$$

where

$$\exists^{\geq n} x \phi(x)\\
= \exists x_1 \ldots \exists x_n (x_1 \neq x_2 \land \ldots \land x_1 \neq x_n \land \ldots \land x_{n-1} \neq x_n \land \phi(x_1) \land \ldots \land \phi(x_n))$$

It is obvious that "$< n$" = "not $\geq n$", and "$ > n$" = "$\geq n+1$".

With these observations, we have (I am using "$=$" for definitional equivalence, and "$⟚$" for logical equivalence):

$$\begin{align*}
& \neg \exists^{=n} x \phi(x) & \\
= &\neg (\exists^{\geq n} x \phi(x) \land \neg \exists^{\geq n+1} x \phi(x)) & \text{(def. } \exists^{=n} \text{)}\\
⟚\ & \neg \exists^{\geq n} x \phi(x) \lor \neg \neg \exists^{\geq n+1} x \phi(x)) & \text{(DeMorgan's law)}\\
⟚\ & \neg \exists^{\geq n} x \phi(x) \lor \exists^{\geq n+1} x \phi(x)) & \text{(double negation elimination)}\\
= & \exists^{<n} x \phi(x) \lor \exists^{>n} x \phi(x) & \text{(def. } <n, >n \text{)}
\end{align*}$$

which is precisely the equation in the first paragraph.

Comment: I think it might be nice to define $\exists^{=n} x \phi(x)$ similar to how you define $\exists^{<n} x \phi(x)$ and $\exists^{>n} x \phi(x)$, and then *derive* $$\neg \exists^{=n} x \phi(x)\\
= \exists^{<n} x \phi(x) \lor \exists^{>n} x \phi(x)$$  Of course, for a definition of $\exists^{=n} x \phi(x)$, you'd probably end up with a statement that turns out to be of the form $\exists^{\ge n} x \phi(x) \land \neg \exists^{> n} x \phi(x)$ with $\exists^{\ge n} x \phi(x)$ being defined as $\exists^{> n-1} x \phi(x)$

Comment: @Bram28 Thanks for the suggestion, I appended a paragraph. (Still kept the end result the first paragraph to make the answer more readable.)

Comment: Cool! Thanks. I was going to do this, but then saw that you were largely there. :)